# how to handle exponential values in informatica

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, informatica

I'm trying to load a csv file with exponential values for few fields into a SQL Server table. These exponential values need to be converted into varchar format show below. I have tried few scenarios which didn't go well. Can you suggest me how to handle these values?

Input Value: 1.12001E+17
Expected Output: 1000000JPM10000000

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

Use to_char(input value) in expression.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whats 1000000JPM10000000. Do you mean you want 1.12001 * 10 Power(17). If yes, you can split the string and handle separately.

`v_col_exp_val = SUBSTR(col_name, instr(col_name,'E+'))`
  `v_col_base_val = SUBSTR(col_name,1, instr(col_name,'E+'))`
`out_col_name = IIF ( instr(col_name,'E+')=0, col_name, v_col_base_val * POWER( 10, v_col_exp_val)`

This considers if the data has exponential values or not as well.

HTH

Comment: The standard record for this field look like "1000000JPM10000000" but some of them were receving as exponential values "1.12001E+17" which need to be converted into "1000000JPM10000000".

Comment: i see, i think you can use above answer to get value  = 100000000000000000 (1 followed by 17 0s.). And then insert JPM1 on proper position.